# wordpress page id in friendly url

Tags: wordpress

How to get the page id in wordpress in the case of friendly url?

Comment: What do you mean? Isn't it located within the permalink link (if your theme uses one)?

Comment: In wordpress using htaccess I create friendly urls for some pages.in that case i don't get the page id and can't use the function is_page(id) for checking the page id.

Comment: So you aren't working with PHP? I'm a bit confused.

Comment: I don't get u. In the wordpress site i make the changes( user friendly url).

Comment: See my answer. Your question is a bit vague... And also, *accept answers*. You asked 18 questions, and accepted less than a third of them. When you accept, it helps others with similar problems find the solution more quickly.

Comment: Please edit your question to add more details about what you're trying to do and what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 2):

Inside the Loop: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_ID

Outside the Loop: `global $wp_query; $id = $wp_query->post->ID;`

Comment: Sorry I thought you were trying to get the id of the post in the theme, plugin or w/e...

Comment: In the header.php I used the function is_page(id).But its not working because of the user friendly url.

Comment: the code in header is                                    if(is_page(73) ||  is_page(101)) { include("file.php");}  and the url is http://site/service/category/cat_title.

Comment: No,its not in any loop.I think due to the url rewriting , not execute the function(is_page) properly

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're talking about doing it via the Admin interface. Can't you just add it into the `custom format` textbox using the `%post_id%` string:

```
/archives/%post_id%
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are within the Loop (most of the time meaning within the `while(have_posts())` you should be able to use: `global $post; $id = $post->ID;` to get the ID